# Average Value: Interval

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

The average value of a function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is $Avg = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$

**Prove**:
If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then the average value of $f$ on an interval centered at $a$ approaches $f(a)$ as the interval size approaches $0$. I understand the intuition behind the problem but I am having a hard time of rigorously writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\frac  1{b-a}\int_a^{b} f(x)dx-f(a)|$ can bw written as $|\frac  1{b-a}\int_a^{b} [f(x)-f(a)]dx|$ which does not exceed $\frac  1{b-a}\int_a^{b} |f(x)-f(a)|dx$. Can you finish?

Comment: I'm getting confused between the $a$ in the problem v.s. the $a$ in the interval. I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @LetmeKnow There is only one $a$. $b$ is  a variable point which tends to $a$. Choose $\delta$ such that $|x-a| <\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(a)| <\epsilon$. Note that if $|b-a| <\delta$ then $|x-a| <\delta$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. Hence we get  $|f(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x$ in the interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: Sorry, now where does the integral from above get included in this? I see that $1/(b-a) < 1/\delta$.

Comment: Also, why do you take absolute value of this particular integral?

Comment: $\frac 1 {b-a} \int_a^{b} \epsilon dx=\epsilon$ since $b-a$ cancels. Absolute value is required by definition of limit. We have to show that $|A-f(a)| \to  0$ where  $A$ is  the average.